# With Jasmine-jQuery I tried to change fixture HTML but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, tdd, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am newbie of **Jasmine-jQuery**. I tried to use fixture HTML but test doesn't pass.

**fixture.html:**

```
<html>
<body>
  <p id="0">
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**fake_code_for_question_spec.coffee:**

```
describe "FakeCodeForQuestion", ->
  describe "with HTML fixture", ->
    beforeEach ->
      loadFixtures "fixture.html"   ### Load Fixture
      @obj = new FakeCodeForQuestion

    describe "#addText", ->
      beforeEach ->
        @obj.addTextToParagraph0()   ### Change DOM

      it "should add text", ->
        expect($('p#0')).toHaveText "text"   ### Get Changed DOM
```

**fake_code_for_question.coffee:**

```
root = exports ? this
class root.FakeCodeForQuestion
  addTextToParagraph0: ->
    $('p0').text "text"
```

**Jasmine Result:**

```
Expected '<p id="0"> </p>' to have text 'text'.
```

Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
root = exports ? this
class root.FakeCodeForQuestion
  addTextToParagraph0: ->
    $('p0').text "text"
```

Hi again, the issue here is your selector doesnt refer to an element with the id of p0 rather it refers to a non-existant element p0 i.e. similar to how $('body') selects the body element.

You want it to be $('#p0') instead